# Strange distribution of prediction probilities

Tags: h2o

I am using H2O AutoML (python 3.28.0.2) to build a bernoulli GBM model for a dataset.

The dataset is relatively small train/validate/test: 6217 1310 1550

My settings are

automl_params = {
    'include_algos': ['GBM'],
    'balance_classes': True,
    'seed': 1234,
    'sort_metric': 'logloss', 
    'keep_cross_validation_predictions': True,
    'stopping_metric': 'logloss', 
    'stopping_rounds': 5,
    'max_runtime_secs': 3600*3
}

If I now consider a histogram over the p1 probabilities, I find that the model is always very certain (<0.05 and >0.8) about its predictions. However, the performance doesn't fit to that picture at all. I would suspect that my features are pointing too much into the same direction but I am basing myself on the work of an consultant that got with very similar features much more reasonable probabilities (but I can't access the training procedure anymore).

Can someone give me hints in which to focus? I am already working for a month on this problem.

Kind regards,
Robin